# SCILAB code for searching the center of figure

Tags: scilab

I'm looking for the center of the figure in green in terms of a point with these coordinates (X, Y) that I posted:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jPqM.jpg]

I tried to apply Guldin's method, looking for the center of gravity, the moment of inertia, but in vain.

```
 function y = h(x)
  if x < 50 | 210 < x then
    error("Out of range");
  elseif x <= 90 then
      
    y= -57.376067 +9.3746343*x -0.2175008*x^2  +0.0013792*x^3    
   //disp('50-90')
    return;
  elseif x <=100  then

     y=  10330.932 -336.90229*x +3.6300206*x^2  -0.0128709*x^3;
    //disp('90-100')
  elseif x <= 130 then

      y=-6387.7416 +164.65791*x -1.3855814*x^2  +0.0038478*x^3;  
  //disp('100-130')
    return;
  else
      
    y = 5028.1996 -98.786888*x +0.640917*x^2  -0.0013484*x^3; 
  //disp('130-210')
  end
endfunction
t=[50:210];
plot(t,feval(t,h),'r*')


  l=[50 60 90 100 130 150 210]  
  k=[40  20  30 70 55 80 60]
  plot(l,k,'d')

for i=[40  20  30 70 55 80 60]
    
 teta=[0: 220]
 beta=linspace(100,100,221)

plot(teta,beta,'*')   
teta1=[100:160:221]
 beta1=linspace(100,160-2*rand(),221) 
 plot2d3(teta1,beta1) 
 end





a=gca()
a.sub_ticks = [5,5]
a.grid_thickness = [0.05,0.05];
a.grid = [-1,-1]
a.grid_position = "foreground"
//a.grid_thickness = [0.05,0.05]

xgrid(0)
C=[50 60 90 100 130 150 210]
//for j=1:size(C,'c')
//C(j)
//if c(k)<=50 then
// (m=k+1& c(m))

J=numderivative(h,t) /*jacobien*/


//f=C(j)
// J=numderivative(h,i) /*jacobien*/
 deff('[z] = h2(k)', 'z = h(k)-100');     
// disp(C(j))
//for i=[157.56011:204.1084]

[x,fx,v]=fsolve([150,200],h2)
disp(x)
disp(fx)
plot(x,fx+100,)
disp(v)
//plot(x,h2,'d')
//end
//po=[50 60 90 100 130 150 210]
//co=[40 20 30 70 55 80 60]
lh=linspace(157.56011,204.1084);
lpo=feval(lh,h);
 xfpoly(lh,lpo)
e=gce()
e.background=13
```